# MySQL set a rule that make sure that a only one of two columns may be filled with value

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to set a "rule"/index in MySQL database, so if we got two columns:
Cancelled and Claimed, then only one of them may be filled with value.

So if we set cancelled to 1, then claimed cannot be 1 and same way if it was the other way?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended solution here would be to change the schema so that it has *one* column whose status is either `cancelled` or `claimed`, *if* these are non-NULL boolean columns having therefore only 2 possible states.

You could do what you want with a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, but that seems like piling additional complexity over an already overly complex schema.

Something like the following, though the syntax probably needs work, as I don't do `UPDATE` triggers often:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_status` BEFORE UPDATE ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  /* If the claimed was set to 1, set cancelled to 0 */
  IF OLD.cancelled = 1 AND NEW.claimed = 1 THEN 
    SET NEW.cancelled = 0;
  /* Or the opposite.... */
  ELSEIF OLD.claimed = 1 AND NEW.cancelled = 1 THEN
    SET NEW.claimed = 0;
  END IF
END
```

Comment: @pst There could still be one column whose value is otherwise `NULL`.

Comment: @pst I don't see the problem. Imagine a single column `status ENUM('cancelled', 'claimed', 'pending', ...)`. You could add as many values as necessary, and allow `NULL` on this column (or not) as the business rules dictated.

Comment: @pst I added a bit of clarification, and a basic trigger too.